# Kernel panic at boot - Ubuntu 14.04 with 3.13.0-140-generic

Tags: kernel

Trying to boot I get the following kernel panic just before I would enter my password (Ubuntu 14.04 with Linux kernel 3.13.0-140-generic):

[image]

I am able to boot with the older kernel 3.13.0-139-generic.

I reinstalled the linux-headers-3.13.0-140-generic and linux-image-3.13.0-140-generic using synaptic, now I don't even see the output anymore, only a black screen.

Uninstalling Teamviewer solved the problem! I only tried it because it was mentioned in the posted screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: Uninstalling Teamviewer solved the problem! Only tried it because it was mentioned in the posted Screenshot.